# Meaning of "ill-formed declaration" in L(n)

Tags: c++, constructor, declaration, ambiguity

A [code snippet from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization#Notes) is like this:

```cpp
struct M { };
struct L { L(M&); };
 
M n;
void f() {
    M(m); // declaration, equivalent to M m;
    L(n); // ill-formed declaration
    L(l)(m); // still a declaration
}
```

`L(n);` is commented with **"ill-formed declaration"**.

But nearly all compilers issue message like this: no default constructor exists for class "L". That is to say, it's not considered to be ill-formed, right? Because if i throw a line `L() = default;` into L's body, it compiles successfully.

Is the comment wrong or misleading or compilers are not strictly standard-conforming?

**Follow Up**

Seems that i made something wrong with **ill-formed**:

> ill-formed - the program has syntax errors or diagnosable semantic
> errors. A conforming C++ compiler is required to issue a diagnostic, > even if it defines a language extension that assigns meaning to such > code (such as with variable-length arrays). The text of the standard > uses shall, shall not, and ill-formed to indicate these requirements.

In light of that, that line is semantically wrong.

Thanks, for you guys' answers and comments.

Comment: ill-formed means you will get a compiler error if you try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the example demonstrates that declarator may be enclosed in parentheses.

So this declaration

```
M(m);
```

is equivalent to

```
M m;
```

that is there is declared an object `m` of the type `M`.

However this record

```
L(n);
```

can be considered as an expression statement with calling the constructor `L( M & )` with the argument `n` of the type `M` or as a declaration.

The C++ Standard resolves such an ambiguity as a declaration instead of the expression statement. So in this record `n` is the name of the created object. But the class `L` does not have the default constructor. So the declaration is ill-formed because the structure `L` does not have the default constructor that is required for this declaration.

From the C++ 14 Standard (6.8 Ambiguity resolution)

> 1 There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
> and declarations: An expression-statement with a function-style
> explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
> indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
> with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration.

To make an expression statement instead of the declaration you can write for example

```
( L )( n );
```

This record

```
L(l)(m);
```

is a correct declaration. There is declared the object `l` of the type L using the constructor `L( M & )`.

Comment: Seems that L(n) is interpreted as L n = L();